# having a template loop through decendants of child nodes XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I´m very new to XML / XSLT and I´m having a hard time understanding the looping through root - child nodes and decendants of child nodes.

For example I have a XML file which is linked to my XSL file and in that XML file there are several Child nodes with decendants in it. see below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="TEST.xsl"?>
<student>
          <alumno id="001">
                    <nombre>Samuel</nombre>
                    <apellido>Van Bladel</apellido>
                    <email>Samuelvanbladel@gmail.com</email>
                    <foto><img width="800" height="800" alt="bla bla" src="test.png"/></foto> 
                    <expediente>NX0001R</expediente>
                    <curso>1</curso> 

                        <modulos>
                              <modulo1>
                                  <modulonom>daw1</modulonom>
                                  <nota>10</nota>
                                  <comentario>Muy bien hecho hasta el techo</comentario>
                              </modulo1>

                              <modulo2>
                                 <modulonom>daw2</modulonom>
                                  <nota>10</nota>
                                  <comentario>Muy bien hecho hasta el techo</comentario>                              
                              </modulo2>
                        </modulos>
         </alumno>
  </student>
```

I understand that the hierarchy here is student/alumno/modulos/modulo1 or modulo2 but when I would like to loop through them in my XSL i can until student/alumno or if I select student/alumno/modulo I can loop through modulo but I lose the information in alumno (name , last name etc)  which I understand is expected because im inside Modulos  but I would like to know how I can get these to be looped through all together .
XSL below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</body> 
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="alumno">
<p>
<xsl:apply-templates select="nombre"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="apellido"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="curso"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="modulonom"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="nota"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="comentario"/>
</p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nombre">
Nombre: <span style="color:#ff0000">
<xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
<br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="apellido">
Apellido: <span style="color:#00ff00">
<xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
<br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="curso">
Curso: <span style="color:#00ff00">
<xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
<br />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="modulonom">
Nombre Modulo: <span style="color:#00ff00">
<xsl:for-each select="."/></span>
<br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nota">
Nota: <span style="color:#00ff00">
<xsl:for-each select="."/></span>
<br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comentario">
Comentario: <span style="color:#00ff00">
<xsl:for-each select="."/></span>
<br />
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML now shows in the browser:

Nombre: Samuel
Apellido: Van Bladel
Curso: 1

But i would like to see all the information within the node

The main question of the post is:
 1. Why is it not showing "modulonom" / nota / "comentario" which are under the "Alumno" node. 
 2. From what I can see it might have something to do with the  which would be the current node it´s in that is Alumno but Modulos is inside alumno and there is where my question comes. 
 3. How to i fix this if possible?

Thanks a lot already

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact result (as HTML code) you want to get in the given example.

Comment: Hi Micheal please ignore that part, thanks (edited it out)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that your instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="comentario"/>
```

is issued from the context of `alumno` and `comentario` is not a child of `alumno`. So the template matching `comentario` is never applied.

The longer answer depends on what you want to get as the output - but you did not answer my question about that. In general, I would suggest you study the [XSLT processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Processing-Model).